# cx_Freeze to include dependent py files

Tags: python, executable, cx-freeze

I am creating the installer for python application by using below setup file

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable 

buildOptions = dict(excludes = ["tkinter"], includes =["idna.idnadata"], optimize=1)

setup(name = "SoftwareGateway" , 
      version = "0.1" , 
      description = "" , 
      options =dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = [Executable("main.py", base = base)])
```

The setup file gets the dependencies by itself but catch here in my case is, the `main.py` calls another python program `fun.py` using the subprocess call. When I run `setup.py`, neither the `fun.py` is getting compiled nor is it going into the directory after installation.

Is there a way I can get `fun.py` compiled to bytecode and pack it along with installer?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `import fun` in your `main.py` and use `fun.__file__` to get the correct location of the compiled fun in your subprocess call (assuming `fun.py` is in the same directory as `main.py`). This should do what you asked for.

But why don't you simply pack the content of `fun.py` into a function and call this function instead of the subprocess call?

Comment: I agree with you on calling them as function instead of subprocess but the code is developed by someone else i am just creating installer for it. At this moment i have no permission to modify the existing code.